# yii2 check errors to show error div

Tags: php, yii2

i am showing this div when errors exist!

I what to write if condition to check wether error are there or not.

```
<?php if(error){ // here?>
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
    <?= $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
    </div>     
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: and do not use short open tag: Use <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

Comment: why you did't use active form ?

Comment: @halojoy Can you explain why?

Comment: @halojoy don't leave unanswered questions :p

Comment: @Yupik Because it is bad standard. And can give you trouble. Script can stop working in worst case.

Comment: @halojoy Do you have any proofs? I don't know where you found that's a bad standard. What troubles? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Yupik I have seen and experienced - the code is displayed. At a server where php is set to not use short_open_tags the code is all broken. You have to believe me. Plain as that.

Comment: Seems that your informations are outdated.`<?=` is not connected to `short_open_tags` setting in `php.ini` since PHP 5.4, it's available always since PHP 5.4, and minimum version of PHP you should have is 5.6. Please stay up to date or don't share things like this until you confirm :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [hasErrors](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#hasErrors()-detail) method.

```
<?php if($model->hasErrors()){ // here?>
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
    <?= $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
    </div>     
<?php } ?>
```